# Relations involving image and kernel of endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f,g$ be endomorphisms of a $K$-vectorspace $V$, $V$ being finite-dimensional.
We are given that $\text{im}(fg)=\text{im}(gf)$ and that $\text{im}\,f+\text{ker}\,g = V$.

Prove that $\text{im}\,f\cap \text{ker}\,g = \{0\}$.

I could only figure out that $\text{im}\,g = \text{im}(gf)$, but then I got stuck. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm not quite awake enough anymore to think hard about this at the moment, but what might be useful to others: have you learned about dimensions yet? If so, there's probably some dimension argument you're allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\let\leq\leqslant\newcommand\im{\text{im}\;}$you want to show $\im g\cap\ker f=\{0\}$. (Otherwise the statement is false, take for example $f=\text{id}$ and $g=0$.)

Main idea: The fact that $\im(g)=\im(f\circ g)$ suggests applying the dimension formula (rank-nullity theorem) $\dim(\ker\alpha)+\dim(\im\alpha)=\dim(A)$ with $\im g$ as vector space and $\alpha=f$: indeed, $\im(f|_{\im g})=\im(f\circ g)=\im g$.
The dimension formula gives $\dim(\ker(f|_{\im g}))=0$, that is, $\im g\cap\ker f=\{0\}$.